# odd indexed Fibonacci numbers for any $n \in \mathbb N, F(2n+1) = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} i F(2n-2i+1)$

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

for any $n \in \mathbb N, F(2n+1) = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} i F(2n-2i+1)$ about odd indexed fibonacci numbers

$$F(n) =$$
\begin{cases} 
      0 & n = 0 \\
      1 & n = 1 \\
      F(n-1) + F(n-2) &  n > 1 
\end{cases}

Claim: For any $n \in \mathbb N, F(2n+1) = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} iF(2n-2i+1)$

Basis:

let $n = 1$

$$F(2(1)+1) = F(3) = 1 + 1 = 2 = 2(1) - 2(1) + 1 + 1 = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{1}i(2(1)+2i+1) \text{ By def of fib seq and it holds}$$

Inductive step: Let $n > 1$. Suppose $F(2j+1) = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{j} i F(2j-2i+1)$ whenever $1 \leq j < n$ [I.H]

What to prove: $F(2n+1) = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} i F(2n-2i+1)$

$F(2n+1) = F(2n) + F(2n-1)$ [def of fib seq; $n > 1$]

[I'm lost here]

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the sum of the first $n$ odd Fibonacci numbers gives the $n^{th}$ even Fibonacci number 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} F_{2i+1}=F_{2n}
\end{eqnarray*}
This is easy to show by induction.

Now to prove your formula 
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{2n+3}=F_{2n+2}+F_{2n+1} =\sum_{i=0}^{n} F_{2i+1}+1+\sum_{i=0}^{n} i F_{2n-2i+1} \\
=1+\sum_{i=0}^{n} (i+1) F_{2n-2i+1} =1+\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} j F_{2n-2j+3}.
\end{eqnarray*}